# Error handling upgrade request TypeError: fetch failed - Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to connect to my socket in next 13. I know that using this new api route is impossible so I used old pages that are ok with sockets and it looks like this:

**page/api/socket**

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const ioHandler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponseServerIo) => {
  if (!res.socket.server.io) {
    const path = "/api/socket/io";
    const httpServer: NetServer = res.socket.server as any;
    const io = new ServerIO(httpServer, {
      path: path,
      // @ts-ignore
      addTrailingSlash: false,
    });
    res.socket.server.io = io;

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {});
  }

  res.end();
};
```

**Frontend**

```
const socketInitializer = async () => {
    try {
      if (isMounted) {
        socket = new (io as any)("http://localhost:3000", {
          path: "/api/socket/io",
          addTrailingSlash: false,
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

But I get this strange error even tought the connection seems to work. I don't know what is happening. Any ideas how to remove this strange error?

Error handling upgrade request TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11413:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async invokeRequest (C:\Users\thesu\noted\node_modules.pnpm\next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\node_mod

code: 'UND_ERR_INVALID_ARG'